# Solving the "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" crash. C++

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, assertion

I have this simple piece of code:

```
    struct A {
        char* str;
        A() : str(NULL) {}
        ~A() { delete[] str; }
    };

    void bar(A a) {
        printf("%s", a.str);
    }

    int main() {    
        A b;
        b.str = _strdup("string");
        bar(b);
        return 0;
    }
```

which causes the assertion
failure. The source of the problem as far as I can gather is the c'tor\d'tor.
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You need a copy constructor, otherwise your `str` field will get shallow copied when calling `bar`, and the destructors of both instances of `A` will try to free the same memory twice. Also `_strdup` uses `malloc`, so you should match it with a call to `free` rather than `operator delete[]`.

For C++, you can avoid all these memory management issues just using `std::string` or even `std::vector<char>`

Example:

```
struct A 
{
    char* str;
    A(): str(NULL) {}

    // Copy Ctor
    A(const A& other): str(strdup(other.str)) {}

    // Copy Assignment
    A& operator=(const A& other)
    {
         if (this != &other)
         {
              free(str);
              str = strdup(other.str);
         }
         return *this;
    }

    // Dtor
    ~A() 
    {
        free(str);
    }
};
```

Or, much simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A 
{
    string str;
};

void bar(const A& a) {
    cout << a.str << endl;
}

int main() {    
    A b;
    b.str = "string";
    bar(b);
}
```

Comment: I added: A(char* s) : str(s) {}. But I still get the assertion failure.

Comment: That's still a shallow copy so you end up copying pointers rather than the memory. For a deep copy, you want to use strdup, e.g., if you are using C functions.

Comment: You might wanna read on copy constructers, that's not one. Try A(A&)

Answer (score 2):

**strdup** uses **malloc** under the covers.

Use **free** to free it instead of **delete[]**.

- malloc/calloc -> free
- new           -> delete
- new[]         -> delete[]